# When I go into page view in my snapshots I only see, "Navigation to the webpage was canceled". Also weird pop-up when recording

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

As mentioned in the title when I go into my Snapshots and page view, all I see is "Navigation to the webpage was canceled", or a blank page. Not sure why this is happening but I would like some help, I am new to LoadRunner sorry if this is a stupid question.

Probably relevant to my issue but I also have a weird message when I am initially recording my script, it pops up sometimes and after I press continue it simply records my script seemingly normally. To clarify it does not always appear when I am trying to record in vugen only occasionally, it is seemingly dependent on which website I am trying to record.

Images for both will be attached.

[Navigation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMdiY.png)

[Recording image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/141vr.png)

Comment: Is this the Microfocus Tours training app or some other app?  Also clarify if your management has sent you through product training for LoadRunner

Comment: I'm a university student and I managed to get access to MicroFocus LoadRunner Professional Trial through signing up with my school email. I am teaching myself basically through various online courses and this is simply a personal project for practice.

Comment: Then you should be using Microfocus Tours and the training material for that product.   If you read the license agreement it is very restrictive on the use of LoadRunner against software you do not own, manage, control, or have direct permission from those with the permissions.

Essentially what you have in your possession is tactical nuclear software.   It should be used with supervision and training.